# Fractional zoom levels

Tags: zooming, leaflet

Is there any way to set a fraction zoom level with setZoom or setView?

I'm trying to allow users to draw using the leaflet.draw plugin on an empty tilelayer where I have drawn a polygon that represents the drawable area. I'd like to have the drawable area fill up as much space as possible within the map div while still showing the entire drawable region.

At zoom level 11.
[image: At zoom level 11]

At zoom level 12.
[image: At zoom level 12]

Ideally, I would like to find an in-between zoom value based on the div width or something like that. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

In [Leaflet](http://leafletjs.com/), no, not currently. This [will be supported in Leaflet 0.8](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/pull/2382), but not until then.

Comment: I spent a while earlier today searching through that thread and the various issues that are linked there. It looked like mourner moved all of the commits to the master branch on [Mar 19](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/pull/2382#issuecomment-38085641)
I got the master branch earlier to try it out and had the same result as with the 0.7.3 and 0.7.1 releases.

Comment: "Rebased on top of master" means that he merged master into the branch, not vice versa. That pull request is not finished or merged.

Comment: ok, so is the easey branch what I would need to grab in order to play with this? Looks like you did some work merging there in March as well. Is there any eta on when 0.8 is going to be finished? Anything I could do to help with it?

Comment: Yep: for what needs to be done, there's a checklist on that page.

Comment: Ok so I think part of the issue is that I am using a non standard projection with proj4leaflet where I have defined the scales to use. When leaflet tries to get the scale in getZoomScale, crs.Scale(toZoom) is returning NaN because no scale exists for the fractional value. I've tried to refactor that function but haven't had any success so far getting it to work. I'll keep digging tomorrow and hopefully I can get something working

Comment: The map options to look for are `zoomSnap` and `zoomDelta`. The source code contains a demo which can be directly accessed via https://cdn.rawgit.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/master/debug/map/zoom-delta.html

Answer (score 1):

Looks like it would be supported in Leaflet 1.0.0-beta.3

https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/pull/3523

Comment: I remember reading that it would be supported eventually. I changed jobs about a year ago and I was never able to get it working with the leaflet version we were using.

Answer (score 0):

Leaflet allows you to set decimal values for a zoom value.  It will then requests tiles with that decimal zoom value.  That would be a problem if you had a tile layer, but since yours is empty it should be fine.

Are you also looking for a way to calculate the best zoom level?  That is not clear in your post, if you are.

Comment: I was first interested in figuring out how to get decimal zoom values working. Then I was going to try to find a way to calculate the best zoom level. I still haven't been able to get the decimal zooms to work. Based on tmcw's responses it sounds like I don't have the right build.